# Firebase array-contains - search through the values not the keys

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

How do you query for a value in an array that has a numeric keyset?

For example this query does not work because I believe it is looking at the indexing rather then the values:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
var users = db.collection("Users");
var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var result = users.where('liked', 'array-contains', currentUser.uid);
if (result.length > 0) {
  return 'You have a match!';
} else {
  return 'No matches';
}
```

[image]

Comment: The `array-contains` operator works on the values in the array, not on their indexes. You might want to log the value of `currentUser.uid` right before running the query to see if it has the value you expect. You could also try with a hard-coded string, to rule out it being caused by the UID lookup.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have actually tried both and it still didn't work so I assumed it was going off of the index's.Now that I understand that is is not the index/values...it must be how I am handling the returned data. Could you tell me what data type is returned? The documentation just states `"This query returns every city document where the regions field is an array that contains west_coast. If the array has multiple instances of the value you query on, the document is included in the results only once."`. Does it return an array or a single user?

Comment: According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#where , your `result` variable is of type "Query", so you should `.get()` it, as explained here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query.html#get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stratubas commented, the problem is in this code:

```
var result = users.where('liked', 'array-contains', currentUser.uid);
```

This code constructs a query, but does not yet execute the query. So `result` is a [`Query` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query). To execute the query, and get the results from the server, you call [`get()` on the query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get), which then returns a `Promise<QuerySnapshot>`. Once the promise results, you can handle the results in the [`QuerySnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot).

```
var query = users.where('liked', 'array-contains', currentUser.uid);
query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
    console.log('You have a match!');
  } else {
    console.log('No matches');
  }
});
```

In more modern JavaScript, the above can also be written as:

```
let query = users.where('liked', 'array-contains', currentUser.uid);
let querySnapshot = await query.get()
if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
  console.log('You have a match!');
} else {
  console.log('No matches');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the credit :) You misspelled the username a little, my ocd sense is tingling :O

Comment: Woops....  So sorry about that. I fixed it, and definitely don't hesitate to fix something that stupid next time (although I hope not from me).